# IE8 via Windows Update (XP) broken

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-xp

I've noticed on 3 of the computers I've serviced in the past week or so that after running Windows Update and installing IE8, I'll get DLL errors and exceptions on the next boot. I believe this is because it's removing old files in favor of new ones, but the DLL's aren't unlinked properly. Additionally, with one of the computers, Windows Update was no longer accessible after the update, and I could no longer access Internet Options. This was resolved by manually installing IE8. Any ideas, and has this happened to anyone else? Note that this only seems to occur on machines running XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ons, toolbars and browser extensions can cause problems when upgrading to IE7 or 8, so disable them before upgrading. I suggest uninstalling toolbars, then reinstall after the upgrade.

In the past Zone Alarm was causing upgrade issues because it was blocking access to the registry, so if you have any security software installed, either disable it first or in the case of ZA, uninstall it first.

Reboot twice after upgrading IE.

Malware can also cause problems when upgrading IE.

.

Comment: This issue was present on either fresh installations of XP Pro SP3 or laptops that were cleaned using Combofix + Malwarebytes + MSE + manual cleaning.